# How to decide which Android API level and SDK versions I need to use?

Tags: android

I am new to Android, and working with a beginner-level test application. I want to complete it with tab-bar and actionbar. I managed to do tab-bar, but I have difficulties implementing action bar. I imported a demo project, but when I run it, a prompt appears, saying that my device is not compatible, which is what confuses me.

My question is, how to decide about the API levels, min and target SDK versions, compatibility devices, AVDs? I am confused. I need an article that clears all this confusion.

Any help will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: This is useful: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Check [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) to know about API Levels of Android and to know about Minimum SDK Version and Target SDK Version, check [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

First document states that:

> API Level is an integer value that uniquely identifies the framework API revision offered by a version of the Android platform.

Second Document states that:

> `android:minSdkVersion`
>   An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.
>
> `android:targetSdkVersion`
>   An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to `minSdkVersion`.
>   This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to `minSdkVersion`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements.

Tab-bar's are common so don't worry about the API level. Actionbars are added in Android 3.0+ (API 11). If you are ok with not to support Android 2.x then you can set your min sdk to level 11. If you want to support Android 2.x you need to implement an actionbar yourself. There is a library for that called ActionBarSherlock but it will take some more effort to make it compatible for Android 2.x.

Comment: One should not use ActionBarSherlock anymore, use http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html